# Cassandra INSERT Column Set<text> Does Not Persist

Tags: jdbc, cassandra, cql

The problem is that when I INSERT a row into a Cassandra table. A column(ciderblocks) does not appear to be persisting.  No exception is generated.  Following is my schema,

```
CREATE TABLE atlascarpenter.registration (
    id timeuuid PRIMARY KEY,
    email text,
    firstname text,
    lastname text,
    cidrblocks set<text>
);
```

My insert is this,

```
INSERT INTO atlascarpenter.registration
    (id, cidrblocks, email, firstname, lastname)
VALUES 
    (now(), {'222.222.222.0/10','111.111.111.0/10'}, 'john.doe@google.com', 'john', 'doe');
```

My query and results are this,

```
select * from atlascarpenter.registration

id, cidrblocks, email, firstname, lastname
54ca6860-6b47-11e6-8ddf-c9ea2c0bd7d2    []  jane.doe@company.com    jane    doe
```

Any idea why cidrblocks is empty?

Comment: replacing `list<text>` instead of `set<text>` in the table creation script might help?

Comment: I tried that as well and same effect.  I think this is a problem outside of my Java program and the JDBC driver.  If I cut/paste the CREATE statement into RazorSQL and run it creates the schema as expected except cidrblocks set<text> is shown as cidrblocks text.  For example, if I generated DDL from the newly deployed table.  I'm thinking this could be a Cassandra bug.  My version tag from cqlsh,[cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 3.7 | CQL spec 3.4.2 | Native protocol v4].  Which version you using?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the problem is RazorSQL.  If I dump the schema or the contents of the table using Cassandra's cqlsh tool I see correct schema and data as expected.  RazorSQL's tool indicated it was compatible with Cassandra but unfortunately it does not appear to support all Cassandra data types.  Or at least it does not support multi-valued types like list and set.  Strange I'm posting my own reply as an answer but I thought this might be helpful to someone else.